# Closing a Scanner throws java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, string, exception, element

I'm writing an RPG combat system from scratch in Java, ambitious right? Well, I'm having some trouble. This is my code:

```
void turnChoice() {
    System.out.println("What will you do? Say (Fight) (Run) (Use Item)");
    Scanner turnChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
    switch (turnChoice.nextLine()) {
        case ("Fight"):
            Combat fighting = new Combat();
            fighting.fight();
        default:
    }

    turnChoice.close();
}
```

When it hits that point in the code I get:

> What will you do? Say (Fight) (Run) (Use Item)
>          Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>             at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
>             at Combat.turnChoice(Combat.java:23)

The class is called Combat, I just want it to give an option to fight or run or use items, I'm trying just the fight method first. Please help, I'm kind of new to Java so don't make things too complicated if possible.

Comment: have u done `import java.util.Scanner;`?

Comment: What is Combat.java line 23?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you are reading using `Scanner` from `System.in`, you should not close any `Scanner` instances because closing one will close `System.in` and when you do the following, `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown.

```
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = sc1.nextLine();
...
sc1.close();
...
...
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
String newStr = sc2.nextLine();      // Exception!
```

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a memory leak?

Comment: `System.in` is closed by the JVM and you should not close it. Don't worry about it. Scanners are just buffer readers.

Comment: @mostruash, so we shouldn't close any scanner, and whenever the app is closed then all scanners will be cleared from the memory, right?