# Scanner : Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create an Utility Class to take inputs from the **Standard Console** using **java.util.Scanner**

```
package dbasics;

import java.util.*;


public class Utils {

    public static int getNumericInput() {
        System.out.println("Enter a integer ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        return n;
    }

    public static int[] getNumericArrayInput(int n) {
        //System.out.println("Enter "+n+"  integers seperated by a whitespace ");
         int[] numbers = new int[n];
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                 numbers[i] =scanner.nextInt();
             }

         scanner.close();
         return numbers;
    }

}
```

While calling the **static** methods in another class the method `getNumericInput()` works fine however the following method `getNumericArrayInput(int n)` results in an exception.

```
package dbasics;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = Utils.getNumericInput();
        System.out.println("Number "+n);
        int arr[] = Utils.getNumericArrayInput(n);
        for(int i : arr) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Running this results in following **exception**

```
Enter a integer 
5
Number 5
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at dbasics.Utils.getNumericArrayInput(Utils.java:21)
    at dbasics.Demo.main(Demo.java:9)
```

**The intresting thing I have noticed is if I comment out the first input procedure the array input works fine**

Comment: You should always use a try<> with resources for classes like Scanner, which are closeable.
It is possible that your first invocation closes the input stream when it is closed.

Answer (score 2):

You are closing Scanner in your function that is causing in Exception: 
Try this:

```
import java.util.*;


class Utils {

    public static int getNumericInput() {
        System.out.println("Enter a integer ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        return n;
    }

    public static int[] getNumericArrayInput(int n) {
         int[] numbers = new int[n];
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                 numbers[i] =scanner.nextInt();
             }

         scanner.close();
         return numbers;
    }

}
public class cn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = Utils.getNumericInput();
        System.out.println("Number "+n);
        try{
        int arr[] = Utils.getNumericArrayInput(n);

        for(int i : arr) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

For more information please read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423519/closing-a-scanner-throws-java-util-nosuchelementexception)

Answer (score 0):

In the first method, don't close the `scanner`

Comment: Won't that result in a leak?

Comment: No it won't, you are still having elements to consume via the stream, why should it be closed ?

Comment: Because it is closeable, so should be closed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: I agree, but if you look deep inside the `Scanner#close`method, its source is also closed, the source here is the `System.in` it will be closed as well

Comment: I understand that closing an instance will result in closing of stream, however when the second method is called, it is again creating a new instance of Scanner, won't that be sufficient to open an input stream again?

Comment: As `System.in` is a static reference, so I guess if it is closed it is not implicitly opened again