# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found. Works before, but not later. I don't know why

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a game, and for whatever reason the Scanner works before in a separate method, but not in this one.

Works in:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner in case of invalid input

for (int i = 1; i <= p.getSpeed(); i++) { // loop to account for invalid direction

if (d.equalsIgnoreCase("right") || d.equalsIgnoreCase("r") && p.getX() <= width - 2) { // right

    if (board[p.getY()][p.getX() + 1] == ' ') {
        board[p.getY()][p.getX()] = ' ';
        p.setX(p.getX() + 1);
        board[p.getY()][p.getX()] = 'P';
    }

    else { // right not open
        System.out.println("Please input a valid direction");
        d = in.nextLine();
        i--;
    }

}
```

Doesn't work in:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner in case of invalid input

int i = 1;

while (i == 1) {

    if (d.equalsIgnoreCase("right") || d.equalsIgnoreCase("r") && p.getX() <= width - 2) { // right

        for (int j = 0; j <= numZombies - 1; j++) {

            if (zombie[j].getX() == p.getX() + 1 && zombie[j].getY() == p.getY()) { // checks each zombie to see if it is one to the right of the player

                zombie[j].subtractHealth(p.getAttack());

                break;

            }

            if (zombie[j].getX() == p.getX() + 2 && zombie[j].getY() == p.getY()) {

                zombie[j].subtractHealth(p.getAttack());
                break;

            }else if (j == numZombies - 1) { // if no zombies are found

                System.out.println("There is no zombie there, please insert a new direction");
                d = in.nextLine();
                i--;

            }

        }

    }
}
```

The methods all work and the logic is fine, I just don't know why it works for the first but not the second one

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?  nothing is jumping out at me.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at monsterGame.Board.playerAttack(Board.java:584)
 at monsterGame.zombieTester.main(zombieTester.java:22)

Comment: Line 584 would be d = in.nextLine();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423519/closing-a-scanner-throws-java-util-nosuchelementexception  this seems to be the same problem... are you closing the scanners?

Comment: Yea, they both close after the loops end

Comment: It could be eclipse, I copied all the code into bluej and works, I dont know why it doesnt in eclipse though

Answer (score -1):

Closing the first scanner was the problem, getting rid of that code fixed it. Thanks Charles